# Finding the points nearest to the edge of a irregular shape inside a cicle c++

Tags: c++, qt

```
bool cancelFlag = true;
   bool useUserSelectionForSubplugs = false;
   bool allowMultipleDevicesInOneDieFlag = false;
   int diesToSearchX, diesToSearchY; 
   diesToSearchX = diesToSearchY = 2;
   PBEdgeInterpolationWindow *edgeInterpolationWindow = new PBEdgeInterpolationWindow(&diesToSearchX, &diesToSearchY, &useUserSelectionForSubplugs, &allowMultipleDevicesInOneDieFlag, &cancelFlag);
   edgeInterpolationWindow->exec();

   if(cancelFlag) return;


   if(fSelectedDeviceList.empty())
   {
          QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Edge Crown Creation"), tr("Nothing to create crown with: only the devices in Selected Devices List will be considered for this operation\nPlease add devices to the \"Selected Devices\" list"));
          return;
   }

   PBWaferMapRevision *pendingRevision = fData->fPending_Revision;
   if(!pendingRevision)
   {
          QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Edge Crown Creation"), tr("Revision to be edited needs to be a PENDING revision"));
          return;
   }

   struct WMDeviceForCrown
   {
          double x, y;
          double wrtShotX, wrtShotY;
          int crownShotRow, crownShotCol;
          WaferDevice *WaferDevicePointer;
   };
   std::vector<WMDeviceForCrown> DeviceForCrownList;

   PBProductData *productData = static_cast<PBProductData*>(fData->Getparent()->Getparent());
   double offsetX = productData->fOffsetX;
   double offsetY = productData->fOffsetY;
   double diesizeX = productData->fDieSizeX;
   double diesizeY = productData->fDieSizeY;


   /* Collect all devices within the edges, assign them coordinates of their first probe */
   if(useUserSelectionForSubplugs )
   {
          qDebug()<<"inside if crown";
          bool noSubplugSelected = true;
          for(int i=0; i<pendingRevision->fShotList.size(); i++)
          {
                 for(int j=0; j<pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fSubPlugList.size(); j++)
                 {
                       if(pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fSubPlugList[j].fIsSelected)
                       {
                              noSubplugSelected = false;
                              PBSubPlug *subPlug = fCurrentRevision->fShotList[i].fSubPlugList[j].fSubPlug;
                              for(int k=0; k<pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fDeviceList.size(); k++)
                              {
                                     WaferDevice *dev = &(pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fDeviceList[k]);
                                     if(!dev->fIsOutsideEE)
                                     {
                                            if(std::find(fSelectedDeviceList.begin(), fSelectedDeviceList.end(), dev->fDevice) != fSelectedDeviceList.end())
                                            {
                                                   double probeX = dev->fDevice->fDevice->fMPFProbeList->fProbeList.front()->fProbe_pos_x; 
                                                   double probeY = dev->fDevice->fDevice->fMPFProbeList->fProbeList.front()->fProbe_pos_y;
                                                   double x = subPlug->fSubplgx;
                                                   double y = subPlug->fSubplgy;
                                                   double w = subPlug->fSubplgwidth;
                                                   double h = subPlug->fSubplgheight;
                                                   if((probeX > x-kDoubleTolerence) && (probeX < x+w+kDoubleTolerence) && (probeY > y-kDoubleTolerence) && (probeY < y+h+kDoubleTolerence))
                                                   {
                                                          WMDeviceForCrown devForCrown;
                                                          devForCrown.WaferDevicePointer = dev;

                                                          double shotX = pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotX;
                                                          double shotY = pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotY;

                                                          devForCrown.wrtShotX = probeX;
                                                          devForCrown.wrtShotY = probeY;

                                                          if(dev->fDevice->fDevice->fMPFProbeList->fProbeList.empty()) return;
                                                          double probe1X = shotX + devForCrown.wrtShotX;
                                                          double probe1Y = shotY + devForCrown.wrtShotY;

                                                          devForCrown.x = probe1X;
                                                          devForCrown.y = probe1Y;

                                                          devForCrown.crownShotRow= pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotRow;
                                                          devForCrown.crownShotCol= pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotCol;

                                                          DeviceForCrownList.push_back(devForCrown);
                                                          //break;
                                                   }
                                            }
                                     }
                              }
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(noSubplugSelected)
          {
                 QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Edge Crown Creation"), tr("Nothing to create crown with: only the selected devices in selected subplugs will be considered for this operation\nPlease select one or more subplugs in the wafer map\nor uncheck option \"consider devices only in selected subplugs\""));
                 return;
          }
   }
   else
   {
          qDebug()<<"inside else crown";
          for(int i=0; i<pendingRevision->fShotList.size(); i++)
          {
                 if(pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotName == "Std shots")
                 {
                       for(int j=0; j<pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fDeviceList.size(); j++)
                       {
                              WaferDevice *dev = &(pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fDeviceList[j]);
                              if(std::find(fSelectedDeviceList.begin(), fSelectedDeviceList.end(), dev->fDevice)==fSelectedDeviceList.end()) continue;
                              if(!dev->fIsOutsideEE)
                              {


                                     WMDeviceForCrown devForCrown;
                                     devForCrown.WaferDevicePointer = dev;

                                     double shotX = pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotX;
                                     double shotY = pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotY;

                                     devForCrown.wrtShotX = dev->fDevice->fDevice->fMPFProbeList->fProbeList.front()->fProbe_pos_x;
                                     devForCrown.wrtShotY = dev->fDevice->fDevice->fMPFProbeList->fProbeList.front()->fProbe_pos_y;

                                     if(dev->fDevice->fDevice->fMPFProbeList->fProbeList.empty()) return;
                                     double probe1X = shotX + devForCrown.wrtShotX;
                                     double probe1Y = shotY + devForCrown.wrtShotY;

                                     devForCrown.x = probe1X;
                                     devForCrown.y = probe1Y;
                                     devForCrown.crownShotRow= pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotRow;
                                     devForCrown.crownShotCol= pendingRevision->fShotList[i].fShot->fShotCol;

                                     DeviceForCrownList.push_back(devForCrown);
                                     //     break; 

                              }
                       }
                 }
          }
   }

   if(DeviceForCrownList.empty())
   {
          QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Edge Crown Creation"), tr("No valid devices for the crown operation. \nNo device from selected devices list could be found in the selected subplugs."));
          return;
   }

   std::vector<WMDeviceForCrown> DeviceOnEdgeList;

   for(int i=0; i<DeviceForCrownList.size(); i++)
   {
          WMDeviceForCrown dev = DeviceForCrownList[i];
          bool quadrantEmpty;


          /* Axes as thick as diesize */
          int xOffset = int(dev.wrtShotX)%int(diesizeX);
          int xReminder = diesizeX - xOffset;
          double xmin = dev.x - xOffset;
          double xmax = dev.x + xReminder;

          int yOffset = int(dev.wrtShotY)%int(diesizeY);
          int yReminder = diesizeY - yOffset;
          double ymin = dev.y - yOffset;
          double ymax = dev.y + yReminder;



          /* First Quadrant */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {

                       if((DeviceForCrownList[j].x>xmax && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>ymax)  )
                       {
                              /*if((DeviceForCrownList[j].y>ymax &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].x>=xmin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].x<=xmax))
                              {
                                     DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                                     continue;
                              }*/
                              /*qDebug()<<"xmin::"<<xmin;
                              qDebug()<<"xmax::"<<xmax;
                              qDebug()<<"ymin::"<<ymin;
                              qDebug()<<"ymax::"<<ymax;
                       */

                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;



                       }

                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }


          //* Second Quadrant */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if(DeviceForCrownList[j].x<xmin && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>ymax /*|| (DeviceForCrownList[j].x<xmin  && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>=ymin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].y<=ymax*/)
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }


          //* Third Quadrant */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if(DeviceForCrownList[j].x<xmin && DeviceForCrownList[j].y<ymin)
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }


          //


          /////* Fourth Quadrant */
                 quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if((DeviceForCrownList[j].x>xmax && DeviceForCrownList[j].y<ymin) /*|| (DeviceForCrownList[j].x<xmax && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>ymin)*/)
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }




                 //            /* Along X-Positive Axis */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if(DeviceForCrownList[j].x>xmax  && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>=ymin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].y<=ymax)
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }


          ////   ///* Along Y-Positive Axis */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if((DeviceForCrownList[j].y>ymax &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].x>=xmin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].x<=xmax) /*&& (DeviceForCrownList[j].x>xmax  && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>=ymin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].y<=ymax)*/ )
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }

          ////



          //            ///* Along X-Negative Axis */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if(DeviceForCrownList[j].x<xmin  && DeviceForCrownList[j].y>=ymin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].y<=ymax)
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }

          ///////* Along Y-Negative Axis */
          quadrantEmpty = true;
          for(int j=0; j<DeviceForCrownList.size(); j++)
          {
                 if(i!=j)
                 {
                       if(DeviceForCrownList[j].y<ymin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].x>=xmin &&  DeviceForCrownList[j].x<=xmax)
                       {
                              quadrantEmpty = false;
                              break;
                       }
                 }
          }
          if(quadrantEmpty)
          {
                 DeviceOnEdgeList.push_back(dev);
                 continue;
          }



   }

   if(DeviceForCrownList.empty())
   {
          QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Edge Crown Creation"), tr("No valid devices found along the edge"));
          return;
   }

   /* Temporary code for visualization */
   //for(int i=0; i<DeviceOnEdgeList.size(); i++)
   //{
   //     QGraphicsEllipseItem *itm = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(DeviceOnEdgeList[i].x-150, -DeviceOnEdgeList[i].y-150, 300, 300);
   //     itm->setBrush(Qt::blue);
   //     fWaferMapView.scene()->addItem(itm);
   //}
```

I have a circle in 2d plane with centre as 0,0 .
Now i have drawn rectangles of fixed sizes all over the circle , rectangle 0,0 is the one which contains centre of circle and then rectangle 0,1 ,02 so on are along x, axis and similarly in all Quadrants.

Now each rectangle has some devices and i knw the x,y of those devices for each rectangle. each rectangle has same devices in it.

Now i am selecting the devices in grey as per this picture:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_oYS4i7-wQMWldWdzRjcG1qekU/edit?usp=drive_web&pli=1

now when i run the above code , I am trying to select the devices at the edges of the selection in grey like this :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_oYS4i7-wQMc0x2cFhSMWE0SmM/view?usp=sharing

but still, some devices are not selected as per this link (see red circle).

so need some help/logic to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `making a shape like attached`: Did you mean to link to an image demonstrating the issue?

Comment: yoohoo! OP, the pic is missing (how did you /not/ notice?)

Comment: i dont have privileges to add any attachement unfortunately :(

Comment: @David yaw,@sehe - i have added a googdrive link and updated my question

Comment: What is the "devices" you mention?

Comment: devices are basically the coordinates in 2d plane, in each square there are about 100 devices(coordinate points)